# Custom ObservableLinkedList would not bind in my Windows store app

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have this custom observable collection

```
    public class ObservableLinkedList<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged, IEnumerable<T>, ICollection<T>, ICollection, IEnumerable
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private LinkedList<T> _list = new LinkedList<T>();

    public ObservableLinkedList()
    {

    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _list.Clear();
    }

    public void Add(T artist)
    {
        _list.AddLast(artist);
    }

    public Model.Artist Find(string p)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return _list.Count();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }


    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int ICollection<T>.Count
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int ICollection.Count
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

Which is bound in some XAML:

```
    <Page.DataContext>
    <viewModel:SearchViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

And the GridView is databinding like this

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Artists}" Grid.Row="1">
```

Where my SearchViewModel in term hands out my ObservableLinkedList, but the UI never gets an update. The scary part is that if I replace my ObservableLinkedList with the official ObservableCollection, then it work just fine.

CollectionChanged and PropertyChanged is always null. I have checked this with a breakpoint in the clear method, in the constructor and in the add method.

Can someone please tell me how to correctly implement this? There must be some way. Infact you do not even have to tell me how to implement this, you can just point me in a direction where someone tells my how binding is done under the helmet. Or how to get even more debug information out from the XAML.

I have tried to remove all the exception throwing and breaking in every method.

Thanks,
Martin Slot

Comment: Do you see any data binding errors in the output window with the debugger attached?

Comment: give us the main model and all other relevant bits (the main model, how u define etc.). Try the debugger as Jer suggested - and put breakpoints on getter/setter-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not had time to paste all my code. If I do this, and only paste the bits and pieces relevant, I think that many would see this question as to long.

I have infact resolved this just now. I have change my code to:

```
    public class ObservableLinkedList<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private LinkedList<T> _list = new LinkedList<T>();

    public ObservableLinkedList()
    {

    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _list.Clear();
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return _list.Count();
    }

    public void Add(T artist)
    {
        _list.AddLast(artist);
    }

    public Model.Artist Find(string p)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Putting break points in all methods, I can see that when the UI has initialized and seen resolved the binding, the CollectionChanged is not null anymore indicating that the UI is aware of the collection. It looks like the GridView wants a Collection and not interfaces. I have tried to implement all interfaces of Collection, without any luck of compiling the code (that is a bit strange). The compiler complains about having two Add methods. I find that a bit odd, but never the less. Inheritance from Collection resolves this. Now I just have to implement the correct notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are basically storing your items inside a private linked list, you need to raise the appropriate events yourself.

For example:

```
public void Add(T artist)
{
    _list.AddLast(artist);
     if (CollectionChanged != null) {
         CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, Item));
    }
}
```

Comment: But how does this account for CollectionChanged and PropertyChanged always being null?